# Looking for pointers on how to debug a "message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, debugging, memory-management

I am getting the following error:

> *** -[URLViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xdb5c3b0

and I am quite confused on how to start debugging this. Can someone please give me some pointers on where to start to look at?

Here's some code if you want to see. This is actually a URL interceptor, so that every links opens up in a presentModalViewController

```
- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url{
    URLViewController * web = [[URLViewController alloc] init];
    web.url = url;
    UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:web];
    [nav.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [nav setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [self.detailViewController presentModalViewController:nav animated:NO];
    [web release];
    [nav release];
    return YES;
}
```

If the URLViewController implementation is any interest, here it is:

```
@implementation URLViewController
@synthesize webview;
@synthesize url;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction) done:(id) sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
}

- (IBAction) openInSafari:(id) sender
{
   [(CVore*)[CVore sharedApplication] openURL:url withOverride:NO];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webview.delegate = self;
     NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview loadRequest:requestObj];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done:)]]; 
     [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(openInSafari:)]]; 
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString* title = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.title"];
    self.title = title;
    //self.navigationItem.title = title;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**UPDATE:**
After tracking this, I think my mistake here is I need to set UIWebView delegate to nil before the [super dealloc] is this correct? As when I did this, it no longer crashes

Comment: @adit: It would help us if we have some code to look at.

Comment: No one wants to write comment for down vote.so delete the post is better option

Comment: I did turn on NSZombies.. but not sure how to look. If you ask for code, which code are you looking for

Comment: @adit: Your `webview` should be released and nil by the you call `dealloc` on `super`. Sounds like you're retaining it at least once too often, does it have a `retain` synthesizer which you're calling anywhere? (See below.)

Comment: no I don' have any extra retain anywhere else as you can see on the code above

Comment: @adit: Setting `webview`'s delegate to `nil` in `dealloc` is a bad work around. If you have to do that you need to rethink the structure of your class. `webview` has an extra retain on it some where or you've created a zombie, otherwise it would already have been deallocated with the view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've released your `URLViewController` instance to soon or you've not retained it. Also check for where you've used `=` instead of using the synthesized setter (potentially creating a zombie), if any. It's hard to be helpful without any code to look at.

__

When the `URLViewController` has been released and deallocated, your `webview` really should be too by the time you call to `super` because it's a class member. However, objects must not retain their delegates (to prevent a "retain-cycle") so if you're some how putting an extra retain on your webview, here or elsewhere, its delegate can still end up being nil and give the resulting crash. For example, do you have a `retain` synthesizer for `webview`? And have you called this at any time?

Comment: No I didn't add any extra retain.. I think the issue is more of sending a message to a delegate after it has been released... the webview is from IB I am just wiring it up